# How do I get a reference to the original object of a collection instance?

Tags: python, instances, collections, dimensions

You can use `Object.instance_collection` to get the "reference to the original collection", but how do I get a reference to the original object itself?

Specifically I'm trying to get the dimension of the original object, since instance objects do not have dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When instancing a collection, you get an empty, and its `instance_type`is `COLLECTION` which also has an `instance_collection` property.

This is also indicated in the object properties panel.

[image]

From that, you can get the objects contained in the collection instance themselves and all their properties (including dimensions, bound box, etc.).